# django manytomany: get object when at least one of the object in the M2M rel meets a condition

Tags: django

Given a Model A that has a ManyToMany relationship to a Model B: how to easily get all the Model A objects that have at least one of the Model B in the relationship satisfying a condition?

For example, how to get all the ModelA that have **at least one ModelB with an OK Status**.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    bobjects = models.ManyToManyField(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):

    OK = 'O'
    KO = 'K'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (OK, 'O.K.'),
        (KO, 'K.O.'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Thanks

Comment: `ModelA.objects.filter(bobjects__status = 'O')`

Comment: oh ok, I did not think it was that simple. So when this a M2M rel, django will actually look for one of them meeting the criteria and that's it, nothing else to add to tell him that?